# Initialize Sequence from formatted Map

Tags: f#

So I have a `Map<int, Map<int, string>>` data structure, and I can print them out well like so:

```
aMap 
|> Map.iter(fun key value -> value 
|> Map.iter(fun k v -> printf "Foo: %d\nBar: %d\nValue: %s" key k v))
```

This works fine, but I want to try and append Map elements with string formatting like above to a `seq<string>`

What would be the most effective way of doing this whilst still being "Functional"?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what it is that you want to do?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Pretty much, get the values of all the associated values in the map, apply those to a formatted string (like the printf above), and store it in a seq<string>.

I think I have nearly got it thanks to the help of s952163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always transform your map to a sequence:
`aMap |> Map.toSeq`

You can also use `Map.map` for other transformations (instead of Map.iter).

Generally it helps to go through the reference section of the Collections you are using: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ee353880.aspx

**EDIT:**

```
aMap
|> Map.toSeq
|> Seq.collect(fun (k,v) ->
    v
    |> Map.toSeq
    |> Seq.map(fun (x,y) -> sprintf "Foo: %d Bar: %d Value: %s" k x y))
|> Seq.iter(printfn "%A")
```

Version 2:

```
aMap
|> Seq.collect(fun x ->
    x.Value
    |> Seq.map(fun y -> sprintf "Foo: %d Bar: %d Value: %s\n" x.Key y.Key y.Value))
|> Seq.iter(printfn "%A")
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Il5zv9

Comment: How would I also be able to apply the string formatting as well

Comment: use Map.map and instead of printf just build your string with "Foo" + key

Comment: let me know if that worked for you or just ping me in chat.

Comment: btw, if you are really into printf I guess you can use sprintf instead

Comment: I'll try for another 15 minutes, then I will try and see if I can get more help